# Sharing of library files between apks

Tags: android

Can I share a library between two applications/apks where it is packed with any one of it?

Answer (score 1):

You can present Activities from one application to another to avoid needing to share libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the kind of data you could use a shared DB or folder/file on the SD card. With files/folders you would need to manage consistency yourself as both applications can run at the same time :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this tutorial page for using library resources - it may help you acheive a shared resources model. Note that android SDK 2.0 and pre-1.5 are not capable of creating libraries for some reason. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject